# Reference Unity Game Object/ Layout in native Android SDK

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

My Unity app talks to a Native Android layer and I'm able to successfully pass my Unity Activity to my Native library using the following code

```
class = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
activity = class.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
```

Is there a similar approach to share Unity gameObjects(ideally a frameLayout) with the android SDK? Or is there any way by which I can reference Unity GameObject (frameLayout) from Native itself using the activity that is already shared?